# Magento Test Automation framework confusion

Tags: selenium, automation, e-commerce, magento-1.4

We are using Magento 1.4 at the moment to develop an e-commerce website. I don't know why we are using old version, but we are.

My task is to set up some automation tests. If possible the idea is to use these tests across different websites which also have been built using Magento 1.4.

I am completely new to Magento. I did some research, found some good links for installation. I could not find this information though.

Can you please answer the below questions and help me please? Thanks.

1. [taf](https://github.com/magento/taf) is the link I found for test automation framework. This does not come with pre-written regression tests. Is that correct? Is this compatible with Magento 1.4?

I found that the above repo is deprecated now and there is a new one being maintained [mtf](https://github.com/magento/mtf). On seeing the installation prerequisites (www.github.com/magento/mtf/blob/master/docs/install-config.md) of this it says  Magento 2 is a must.

I am confused now. I must to use Magento 1.4. Which automation framework can I use? Any ideas? Preferably I am looking for one which has some pre-written testcases for Magento, so that it easier to start off with and build atop.

To install and run Magento I found this as the best link so far. (www.dhmedia.com.au/article/how-install-and-run-magento-test-automation-framework). If you have come across something else better please share.

Overall, is it any better and easier to just forget about MTAF and write own automation tests using say testng(Java) or PHPUnit and selenium? I am talking about user-journey tests on e-commerce platform like Placing an order, Browsing through, Creating wishlist, etc..

I know thats a lot of questions. That is how naive I am wrt to Magento. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/magento/mtf is the new one, "taf" is old one and deprecated. It supports the latest version of MAgento. Basicly it's not a set of test cases, but you can build test suites regarding the test cases that could appear in Magento. It's based on Selenium.

Comment: Thank you Stanjer. You are right. In TAF (github.com/magento/taf) there are only about 5 pre written tests. I don't see anymore functional tests. Am I right? So, it is mostly a framework to build onto then and not really a testsuite which will cover many functional tests like placing an order, cancelling an order, creating a wishlist, deleting items from shopping basket etc ..

Comment: Just noticed the comment. Yes, you are completely right. That's why there is no so much difference if you will build it with that project or will take any of existing selenium bindings. Most of the features you should implement by yourself.